# how change the WAR file name inside EAR when deploying in Eclipse with no Maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, build, war

I have a project in Eclipse which doesn't have maven. Because the EAR will be published in Mainframe and must be copied from certain temporary folder to the final folder by a script, I must have the war file inside of EAR with same name set up in script otherwise it will not work. I am exporting the EAR via Eclipse and, whenever I do it generates the inside war with myapp1.war name and I need it to be MYAPP2.WAR. How do I change it? I found many blogs showing it with Mavem (e.g. new_name.war) but it is not my case. How can I set a different name for war in Eclipse, maybe before or after I build the EAR?

Updated:
For building the EAR file, I only rely on Eclipse IDE. To be more precise, I have a IBM RAD. I clicked in File>Export and choose EAR. I don't have Ant, Maven, Gradle or anyelse other plugin for building.

Comment: You haven't explained how you're "building the ear" with eclipse, but you could install m2e (and then you'd have maven). Or you could use ant (which is another build tool), or sbt or gradle (same).

Comment: I added this information above. I haven't installed any build tool. I am just using Eclipse menu option to export.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a lib file (in your case the name of the WAR File) inside the EAR can only be changed manually when working with Eclipse. You have to change the "archiveName" inside the file pathToYouEar\ .settings\ **org.eclipse.wst.common.component**

There you can set the name to whatever you like:

```
<dependent-module archiveName="MYAPP2.WAR" deploy-path="/" handle="module:/resource/yourwarproject">
        <dependent-object/>
        <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```